Why does an incorrect combinatorial calculation give a correct result, while a seemingly correct one gives a result which is incorrect?
I'm considering the complete 3- partite graph G on the six labelled vertices 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 which consists of the three parts (not edges) {1,4}, {2,3}, {5,6}. (These three sets form a partition of the vertex set.) To make G 3-partite complete, we need 12 edges.
According to Kirchhoff's theorem, the number of spanning trees of G can be determined by computing a cofactor of a six by six Laplacian matrix. The result of such a computation seems to be 384.
However I've been trying to determine the number of spanning trees in a combinatorial way also, not using the mentioned theorem. Instead I'm using the fact that a graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges is a tree if and only if it's acyclic.
The number of spanning trees of G should be equal to the number of ways to select five of the twelve edges while avoiding to include a cycle. So from the number $\binom{12}{5}$ we must subtract the number of ways to select five of the twelve edges while including one or more cycles.
Now there seems to be 8 triangles in G and 15 squares (cycles of length 4). If we have already selected a triangle, two additional edges can be chosen in $\binom{12-3}{2}$ ways, and if we have already selected a sqare, one additional edge can be selected in $\binom{12-4}{1}$ ways.
Unfortunately, there are certain combinations of five edges which form two triangles and one square, so we can't calculate the number of spanning trees of G like this:
$\binom{12}{5}-8\binom{12-3}{2}-15\binom{12-4}{1}$
By doing that we subtract the problematic selections of five edges more than once, which means that we should get a number that's  too small.
But the number that we get from the mentioned incorrect calculation is in fact the correct one, namely 384, and what makes things even more confusing is that we get an incorrect number if we correct the calculation and make sure that we count everything exactly once.
For each triangle there are exactly three selections of two additional edges which give a problematic total selection, and for 12 of the squares, there is exactly one selection of an additional edge which gives a problematic total selection. For three of the squares, no additional edge gives a problematic total selection, so the correct number of spanning trees of G should be:
$\binom{12}{5}-8\left(\binom{12-3}{2}-3\right)-12\left(\binom{12-4}{1}-1\right)-3\binom{12-4}{1}-4-8$
At the end, we subtract the $4 + 8$ problematic selections of five edges.
This enhcanced, careful calculation looks correct, but it gives the incorrect result 408, which is difficult to understand. What's going wrong here?

For the sake of all that is holy please use \binom{}{} in the future.

Ok, I didn't know this and had to improvise.

The calculation $384 = \binom{12}{5} - 8\binom{12-3}{2} - 15 \binom{12-4}{1}$ is wrong, but it is wrong in two opposite ways that cancel out.
As mentioned in the question, there are $12$ subgraphs with $5$ edges (such as the subgraph induced by the vertices $\{1,2,3,5\}$) that contain two triangles and a $4$-cycle, and these have been "overcorrected" in the calculation above. They are not spanning trees, so they should be counted $0$ times; however, they are actually counted $-2$ times (counted once in $\binom{12}{5}$, and "uncounted" twice by $-8\binom{12-3}{2}$ and once more by $-15\binom{12-4}{1}$). To fix this error, we should add back $2 \cdot 12 = 24$.
However, there are also $24$ cycles of length $5$ in the graph! For example, there's the cycle $(1,2,4,3,5,1)$. Each of these cycles is counted in the calculation above, and shouldn't be; to fix this error, we should subtract $24$.
The two errors are (coincidentally!) errors by the same amount in opposite directions, so they cancel out in the initial calculation. Correcting just one of them, but not the other, gives an incorrect value.

Ok, great! I will try to check all of this.

There should be no edge between the vertices 2 and 3 since they belong to the same set in the partition, so I don't think that there are any cycles of length five.

Isn't the subgraph induced by the vertices 1, 2, 3 and 4 a cycle of length four?

@AA No, it has five edges: it's only missing the edge $14$.

But there is no edge between the vertices 1 and 4 in the original graph.

There is no edge between the vertices 1 an 4, also not between the vertices 2 and 3, and also not between the vertices 5 and 6. Every other possible edge is present though.

Sorry, when I saw that you deleted the edge $14$, I assumed that the pattern would continue (deleting $25$ and $36$) and didn't read further. I'll edit my examples to match the $14$, $23$, $56$ deletions.

Oh, I think that I see the cycles of length five now. I don't understand how I could miss them.

My second, corrected calculation seems to be correct apart from missing the 24 cycles of length five. I was actually looking for a way to subtract 24 more edge selections than I had already subtracted.

It seems like you view a complete r-partite graph as a complete graph where certain edges have been deleted. Does this way of viewing it make the problem at hand easier?

I'm not sure I suggest it in general, but I think it's a reasonably nice view of the graph here, when there's just a few isolated edges missing. It helps for some parts of this problem. For example, it makes it easy to see that the $\binom62 = 15$ induced $4$-vertex subgraphs consist of $3$ induced $4$-cycles (where we pick both endpoints of two deleted edges) and $12$ of the exceptional $5$-edge subgraphs (where only one deleted edge is included among the $4$ vertices).
